# How are dependant quests generated in Guild Wars 2?

Tags: mmo, rpg

I recently read that Guild Wars 2 uses a system where the creation of quests depends on which actions user took when they were presented another quest. An example was: There might be a quest to protect a person. If users do not take this action, the person might be kidnapped and later there is a quest to rescue this person.

Is there any information on whether the creation of these quests is somehow automatic? From the article it sounded like automatically, but from the specific example you could also guess that people just created a task-set where they added conditions (Task 1 taken: OK; Task 1 not taken: Show Task 2).

From what I heard about AI they might also have implemented some sort of a huge neural network to make decisions?

Comment: Sounds like a "how was this *entire game* made"-question.

Comment: I am not entirely sure this is appropriate for this site, since it doesn't really relate to any specific problem *you* (or anybody else) are having developing a game (thus, it's very localized) and it only really can be answered by somebody who worked on Guild Wars 2. I answered you, since I *did* work on Guild Wars 2, but I also think this should be closed.

Comment: Sounds like: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/40519/what-is-the-logic-behind-dialog-trees

Comment: Yeah sorry: “and it is not about what technology some particular game used” from the Gamedev SE FAQ. Close it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where did you read this? It is quite incorrect.

In Guild Wars 2, your personal storyline ("quests") branch only at specific points designated by the designers. Those branches are gated on either your character creation choices (such as which class of society you hail from) or choices you make in conversations with important NPCs during your storyline.

All of the character creation choices are very explicitly spelled out in your character creation "mad lib" and all the conversation choices during the game have unique conversation icons and very explicit text saying "once you choose this you can't change your mind" (or similar).

Similarly, events that occur within the world have gating conditions whereby some of them will not start or become available without players having completed another event already, and other events are controlled by the success or failure of precursor events. For example, in the human starter zone, an event can occur where bandits try to poison a water supply. Two different subsequent events can occur depending on whether or not the player base manages to defend the water supply. This is entirely pre-scripted.

There is no AI or dynamic cleverness going on at all.

Comment: but then there is my answer. “This is entirely pre-scripted.“ My statement “From the article it sounded like automatically” was only because of the total sound of the article. They never mentioned it was automatically, but they described the world as very flexible or similar. Yet, I cannot find the exact location where I read it.